# Проблема с выводом значения по умолчанию

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Я написал запрос и он работает верно, но когда дело дошло до добавления значения по умолчанию, я получаю ошибку:

> "System.NotSupportedException: "Неподдерживаемая перегрузка, используемая для оператора запроса "DefaultIfEmpty"."

Пробовал также помещать дефол не в сам запрос а в цикл foreach, но результат тот же. С чем может быть связана данная ошибка и как её исправить?

```
int k = 3;
var rezult = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Kod == k).GroupBy(x => x.Year)
                .Select(x => new { a = x.Where(y => y.Time > 15).Count(), b = x.Key })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.a).ThenBy(x => x.b)
                .Select(x => "Количество месяцев " + x.a.ToString() + ", год " + x.b.ToString()).DefaultIfEmpty("Нет данных");
foreach (var g in rezult){
   Console.WriteLine($"{g}");
}
```

Comment: Не по теме, чисто совет: Используйте наконец интерполяцию строк! Это будет понятней и нам и вам. А то эти плюсы, кавычки, брр... `$"Количество месяцев {x.a}, год {x.b}"` приятней же? А по поводу вопроса, попробуйте перед `DefaultifEmpty` поставить `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, такая конструкция работает. Но вот интересно почему здесь необходимо использовать эту конструкцию? В аналогичных ситуациях обходился без неё и все работало

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а интерполяция разве будет работать не на *материализованном* результате?

Comment: не все методы расширения могут выполнятся на стороне сервера, `AsEnumerable` выполняет запрос и получает на клиент результат, а дальше linq может творить чудеса

Comment: @Bald, интерполяция — это всего лишь синтаксический сахар и компилятор сначала разворачивает ее в `string.Format`. Ну т. е. если EF умеет работать со `string.Format`, то и с интерполяцией справится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы используете `Entity Framework`. Так вот, в нем не все LINQ операции поддерживаются, а в некоторых случаях так вообще выбрасываются исключения, что не удалось преобразовать код в запрос.

Если верить вот [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502367/4244707) ответу на EnSO, то поддержка данного метода появиась не сразу => возможно, вы используете старую версию EF. Решение- это обновиться до более новой версии.

Так же, по идее, должно помочь если вы перед `DefaultIfEmpty` вызовите `ToList`.